# Передача переменных из activity в класс

Tags: android, java, классы

Каким образом возможно передать переменную, которая изменяется в созданный класс, который не является activity, и intent соответственно не получается использовать. В классе у меня реализована своя вьюшка.

Comment: Поясните вопрос. Если класс - это некоторый View который отображается внутри вашей активити, то у вас должен быть экземпляр этого класса, которому вы можете передать все что угодно.

Comment: Да, это некоторый view, но как ему что-то передать?

Comment: Эм. Написать соответствующий метод и вызывать его?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

или сделать переменную статической и вызывать её class.variable

Comment: Это самая ужастная идея для этого случая.